# Django Error --SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, django

It seems that i am stuck. I need your help in order to fix this error.
I think the regex on the URL is rotten. Any help will be much appreciated.

This is the error:

> File "/Users/cohen/Documents/project/sanctions/batches/urls.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from . import views   File "/Users/cohen/Documents/project/sanctions/batches/views.py", line 23
>       def detail_businessname(request):
>         ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

These are my models:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Batches(models.Model):
    BatchNumber = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    FileName= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    UploadedDate= models.DateField(max_length=250)
    UploadedBy = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    NumberOfRows= models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Hits= models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Status= models.CharField(max_length=250)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Batches"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.FileName + '- ' + str(self.Hits) + '- ' + str(self.NumberOfRows) + '- ' + self.Status



class BusinessName(models.Model):
    AccountingCode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    RefID = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="")
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Aliases = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    City= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ZipCode= models.IntegerField(null=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Country= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    TypeOfSanction= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Monitoring= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    BatchNumber= models.IntegerField(null=True)  # tr pus automat
    FileName= models.CharField(max_length=250)  # tr pus automat1
    UploadDate = models.DateField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    UploadBy= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    Decision= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus Ulterior
    Status= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    EngineDecision= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    WhoAdjudicated= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    DateOfAdjudication= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    SdnType = models.CharField(max_length=250)  #Entity or Individual

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Business Names"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.FullName + '-' + self.Address  + '-' + self.City + '-' + '-' + self.State + '-' + self.Country

class Individuals(models.Model):
    AccountingCode = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    RefID = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    FullName = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    FirstName= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Lastname= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    DayOfBirth = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    MonthOfBirth = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    YearOfBirth= models.IntegerField(null=True)
    FullDOB = models.DateField(max_length=250)
    Aliases = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    City= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ZipCode= models.IntegerField(null=True)
    State = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Country= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    TypeOfSanction= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Monitoring= models.CharField(max_length=50)
    BatchNumber= models.IntegerField(null=True)  # tr pus automat
    FileName= models.CharField(max_length=250)  # tr pus automat
    UploadDate= models.DateField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    UploadBy= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    Decision= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus Ulterior
    Status= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    EngineDecision= models.CharField(max_length=250) # tr pus automat
    WhoAdjudicated= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    DateOfAdjudication= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    More= models.CharField(max_length=250)
    SdnType = models.CharField(max_length=250)  #Entity or Individual

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Individuals"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.FullName + '-' + self.Address + '-' + self.City  + '-' + '-' + self.State + '-' + self.Country
```

This is my views:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import BusinessName
from .models import Individuals
from .models import Batches

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    all_Batches = Batches.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for batch in all_Batches:
        url = '/batches/' + str(batch.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + str(Batches.BatchNumber)+ '</a><br>'
    return  HttpResponse(html)

def detail(request, BatchNumber):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Batches ID:"  + str(BatchNumber + "</h2")


def detail_businessname(request):
    all_BusinessNames = BusinessName.objects.all()
    html = ''
    for BN in all_BusinessNames:
        url = '/businessname/' + str(BusinessName.id) + '/'
        html += '<a href="#"' + url + '">' + BusinessName.FullName + '</a><br>'
    return HttpResponse(html)


def detail_individuals(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Individual Names ID:"  + str(Individuals.id) + "</h2")
```

And these are the urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    # /batches/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # /batches/2
    url(r'^(?P<batches_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail, name="detail"),

    # businessname/1
    url(r'^(?P<businessname_id>[0-9]+)/$',views.detail_businessname, name="detail_businessname"),

    # individuals/1
    url(r'^(?P<individuals_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail_individuals, name="detail_individuals"),
```

Thank you a lot,
Cohen

Answer (score 2):

You miss closed braket

```
return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Batches ID:"  + str(BatchNumber + "</h2"))
```

Comment: @JohnCohen If you get a syntax error and can't figure out why, looking at the previous line will normally help.